# Ошибка: "SyntaxError: can't assign to operator"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я новичок в Python и для практики решил быстро накидать код для **калькулятора выражений**, не прибегая к дыре в безопасности eval(). Вот что получилось написать за пару минут:

```
act*x = 0
act/x = 0
act+x = 0
act-x = 0
calc = input(" ")
if "/" in calc:
    act/x = int(calc.split("/")[-2] / int(calc.split("/")[1])
if "*" in calc:
    act*x = int(calc.split("*")[-2] * int(calc.split("*")[1])
if "+" in calc:
    act+x = int(calc.split("+")[-2] + int(calc.split("+")[1])
if "-" in calc:
    act-x = int(calc.split("-")[-2] - int(calc.split("-")[1])
print(act/x + act*x + act-x + act+x)
```

И всё бы ничего, но при попытке выполнения кода я получил следующую **ошибку**:

```
File "lol.py", line 1
    act*x = 0
    ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможную причину ошибки и как её исправить.

Comment: у вас синтаксическая ошибка в первой же строке: невозможно назначить оператор

Comment: @Arendach  вы просто перевели ошибку?..

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-make-a-simple-calculator-program-in-python-3

Comment: ну да, так и есть, причину я сказал, как исправить тоже бы сказал но не силен в пайтоне (

Comment: @sensoid, для того чтобы понять, что этот код нерабочий не нужно переводить, это и так очевидно. Объясните, что вы хотели сказать первыми четырьмя строками?

Comment: @insolortiredofthisdrama  добавил переменные ради галочки, чтобы в последней строке не было name error'a

Comment: Естественно. Имена переменных не могут содержать знаки арифметических операций - только буквы, цифры и знаки подчеркивания, и не начинаться с цифры.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В первых четырех строках вы создаете 4 переменные. Однако имена, которые вы им даете - ошибочные, так нельзя называть переменные в Python. Они могут содержать только буквы, цифры (причем с цифры начинать нельзя) и знаки подчеркивания.

Арифметические операции `* - + /` использовать нельзя.